# Installing Google Web Toolkit Developer Plugin

Tags: google-chrome, gwt

As i am working through the google app engine, i am trying to set up my first "Hello World" app running in my Chrome browser

When (for the first time), i navigate to URL

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/MyTest.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997
```

I non surprisingly get

[image]

Ok, so i should get the plugin from the [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/Google%20web%20toolkit). I don't see anything remotely looking like "Google Web Toolkit Developer Plugin" Same deal for "gwt chrome" search.[enter link description here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/gwt%20chrome)

What am i missing please? How can i install this plugin?

Comment: Click on the blue-box, down-pointing arrow "Download the GWT Developer Plugin For Chrome".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick fix that might help:

1. right click on the chrome icon>Properties>Shortcut
2. add in target: --enable-easy-off-store-extension-install
3. open chrome and navitage to extensions ( chrome://chrome/extensions/ )
4. drag and drop on it the plugin (should be in your download folder
   if you tried to install it before and didn't succeed)

Or this one:

1- Download the extension file from the website and save it to your computer.
2- Click the wrench icon on the browser toolbar.
3- Select Tools > Extensions.
4- Locate the extension file on your computer and drag the file onto the Extensions page.
5- Review the list of permissions in the dialog that appears. If you would like to proceed, click Install.

[Google issues](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7569)

Comment: Adding worked, but now, for some reason, when going to URL, i get "Could not load GWT plugin". Restarted the browser, did not seem to help

Comment: Which one did you try? If you tried the first one .. I am all out of ideas.. Did you see or get any errors?

Comment: I am on a MAC, and (like you suggested) was able to drag and drop. No visible errors

Comment: Can you see it in your Tools>Extension ?

Comment: I'll ask another question about this error. Thank you for helping me install it