# GWT developer tools plugin disabled in the latest Chrome (37).

Tags: google-chrome, gwt, google-chrome-extension

My problem is that the GWT developer tools plugin is disabled in the latest version of Chrome (37). The problem is using it, not installing it. Chrome does resist installation (because it uses NPAPI calls which endanger security, I believe). However with a bit of research I have installed the plugin successfully, using the workaround proposed in [Installing Google Web Toolkit Developer Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12809314/installing-google-web-toolkit-developer-plugin) and in various other places.

However, although it is installed, and shows itself as being installed on the extensions page, Chrome will not allow it to run. I have also tried to solve this from the Extensions page by checking the 'developer' checkbox. No difference. Chrome will not run it. I have tried to find an earlier version of Chrome, which is also recommended as a workaround - looking in such sites as OldApps. They are no longer available - Oldapps tells me I have to go to the Chrome downloads page. It seems that in blocking off all routes to run software that might allow security breaches, the Chrome team has made it impossible to run Google's own Development Toosl. Has anyone else encountered this problem? I haven't been able to find any posts that address this latest stage of the problem, which makes me wonder if it is one of my own making - however I can't make it work.

Any thoughts?

Comment: you should use super dev mode with the latest versions of GWT SDK

Comment: Did you also experience that every time you try to browse to your gwt app, chrome asks you to install again, even though the plugin is already installed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sorry but

[`From GWT Website`](http://www.gwtproject.org/release-notes.html#Release_Notes_2_6_1)

> GWT Development Mode will no longer be available for Chrome sometime in 2014, so we improved alternate ways of debugging. There are improvements to Super Dev Mode, asserts, console logging, and error messages.

http://blog.chromium.org/2013/09/saying-goodbye-to-our-old-friend-npapi.html

Comment: You are right. It works well with GWT Supper Dev Mode.

Comment: as work around you can use Firefox 24.0 - it works completely fine with GWT plugin , it also has good developer tool in it , just make sure not to update the Firefox 24.0 - to further versions available .